# linker error: undefined symbol _sum in module my.c

Tags: turbo-c

I am getting following error when I add user defined method in library using turbo c
    **linker error**: `undefined symbol _sum in module my.c`
I followed all steps properly:

```
 // 1. create addition.c containing function definatio and compile it
```

addition.c:

```
 addition(int i, int j)
  {
  int total;
 total = i + j;
 return total;
 }
```

Step 2:

Compile `addition.c` file by using `Alt + F9` keys (in turbo C)
`addition.obj` file would be created which is the compiled form of `addition.c` file.

Step 3:
Add it to library using `tlib`

```
c:\> tlib math.lib + c:\ addition.obj
```

Means adding `c:\addition.obj` file in the math library.

Step 4:
Created a file `addition.h` & declare prototype of `addition()` function like below.

```
 int addition (int i, int j);
```

Now `addition.h` file containing prototype of function `addition`.

```
# include <stdio.h>
     // Including our user defined function.
     # include “c:\\addition.h”     
   int main ()
   {
   int total;
   // calling function from library
   total = addition (10, 20); 
   printf ("Total = %d \n", total);
    }
```

Comment: Using a compiler that is old enough to get a driving license in most countries seems like a bad idea... Without us seeing some of the code you are using, it's impossible to help, no matter what compiler you are using.

Comment: Plz help me to figure out this small problem. Its urgent !!

Answer (score 1):

While writtig this command you need to specify full path of Lib and your module u want to add to library.
Just try it !
e.g.

> Tlib  d:\turboc\Lib\CS.lib  + d:\turboc\demo.obj

Answer (score 0):

I tried making an project in TurboC, that option is right in the menu bar, click open, give any name, then add the sourcce code file along with the header file, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have not enabled the graphics library for linking. By default this setting is OFF when you install Turbo C++ version 3.0.
All you need to do is, from turbo c++ menu, goto Options -> Linker -> Libraries... and check the Graphics Library option